# Trying to run a jenkins pipeline for nodejs build & sonarscanner. Build is working fine but getting below error. Upgrading java didn't work

Tags: java, node.js, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I was trying to create a pipeline using Jenkins. The goal was to clean the workspace, checkout the github repository, build the nodejs app and run a sonarqube scanner. The pipeline built the code without any issue but I am getting an error at the sonarscanner stage.

This is the error:

[image: Image of an error from Jenkins pipeline]

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that the upgraded version of java is actually being used, and ensure the correct version is being used as well. This issue is definitely due to a difference in JDK versions so that should be the main thing you look at.

Comment: Found the solution but forgot to update here. The issue was with sonarscanner. I was using version 4.xx.x. which was compiled by using JDK 11. Later I uninstalled it and installed 5.0.1.3006 {which was compiled by JDK 17} and it ran without any issues. Thanks for answering though.